# Is there a way to delete the most recent entry in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: mysql

I want to delete the most recent entry in MySQL using PHP, is there a function that allows me to do that?

$query2 = "DELETE FROM test WHERE _________";

Comment: Only, if you either have just inserted the entry OR you have some indicator/order in your entries (something like a timestamp or autoIncrement)

Comment: Please update your question with the results of `DESC your_table`, replacing "your_table" with the appropriate table name.  If there's no auto_increment column, a date column would work if you ordered by it in descending fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field on your table, you can do this:

`DELETE FROM test WHERE test_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: This query fails if a second client/connection add a *newer* row with a higher ID or if the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` from the last INSERT INTO command wasn't for the table `test` but for a different table.

Answer (score 1):

You need a datetime column which saved the current time during the `INSERT INTO` query. Then you can use the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` keywords to delete the last entry in your table.

```
DELETE FROM
    tab
ORDER BY
    datecolumn DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Check the [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual - 12.2.2 DELETE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html) for the following statement:

> If the DELETE statement includes an ORDER BY clause, rows are deleted in the order specified by the clause. This is useful primarily in conjunction with LIMIT.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = MAX(id) LIMIT 1
```

should also be working if you are using `auto increment`

Comment: If my table name is "test" and the auto increment id is counter_id.

$query2 = "DELETE FROM test WHERE counter_id = MAX(counter_id) LIMIT 1";

That query doesn't seem to be deleting from the table.

Comment: maybe the `LIMIT 1` is giving problems, because it will not find the total maximum, but only the local maximum in your limited records (so max with limit 1 will only show the first row)